# Have hadoop/*-common.jar included still got "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration"

Tags: java, hadoop, rpc

When practicing to realize a "hadoop RPC" sample, I keep getting this error.
According to previous similar questions and answers, I've checked the jar file in my classpath and got [hadoop common.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLUzG.png) It shows that the jar file in the classpath contains hadoop.conf.Configuration.class.
And here's the code to build RPCServer:

```
*package rpc;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server;
public class RPCServer implements MyBizable {
     public String doSomething(String str) {
        return str;
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {
        Server server = new RPC.Builder(new Configuration())        
        .setProtocol(MyBizable.class)
        .setInstance(new RPCServer())
        .setBindAddress("***.***.***.***")
        .setPort(****)
        .build();
        server.start();
    }
}*
```

And still this error shows up, anyone knows how to solve it?
Any help will be greatly appreciated! THX in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven ? 
if yes then add below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No,I don't use Maven.

Comment: Is Maven essential for this case?

Comment: Try once using maven. it will add dependencies on run time so there should be no error like this.

Comment: As i can see that you have already checked for class using grep command.

Comment: I'll try to build it with maven. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I've built it with maven.And compiling, packaging all went well,but when run "java -cp xxx.jar rpc.Server" I got this "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/hadoop/ipc/RPC$Builder at rpc.Server.main(Server.java:9)" .  (´･_･`)

Comment: Class "RPC" is a class of hadoop Commons library.                                                                           And class "RPC$Builder" is an inner class of RPC. So can you please import whole ipc package and check.                                               org.apache.hadoop.ipc.*;